# Android controlling service with different applications

Tags: android, service, timer, singleton

I have an app with an auto log out feature  where I was using a `Timer` to auto log out the user (where user is a static singleton object).

Recently I realized there were some other activities and I have to implement a global log out feature so I tried to implement different `Timers` to each `Activities` and tried to synchronize them, but it wasn't a good approach and it was a pain. Then I turned my face to the services.

What I need to know is a good way to control a single service within different applications. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement bound service, start it, and bind it with two activities.
More information You can find in official developer docs [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a "Bound" service to interact it from different activities.

Here is complete example for Bound service with explanation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Here is his question : "What I need to know is a good way to control a single service within different applications"

Comment: yes off course it is a proper way but implementation of this kind of service is complex.Just read this article you will get better understanding.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. What I understood is that every answer is a documentation about creating a service or binding them to activity where service is a like server and controlling the activities. But in my case, I need the service to act like a client where different servers synchronously control the client, a.k.a my logout timer in the service. The architecture should be like this, A service with a timer, and one activity can stop and start this timer. But this activity can die and restarted again which is the main reason I use service.

Comment: If you read carefully if you create bound service it will keep running untill all activities are gone of mean unbid. so you can bind service from onResume and unbind in onPause

Comment: If you start service with `startService` it will be running until you  kill it. So your timer will running all the time from application start(for example)

Answer (score 0):

> A broadcast is a message that any app can receive. The system delivers
>   various broadcasts for system events, such as when the system boots up
>   or the device starts charging. You can deliver a broadcast to other
>   apps by passing an Intent to sendBroadcast(), sendOrderedBroadcast(),
>   or sendStickyBroadcast().

All that you need to do is to create `BroadcastReceiver`. Add `IntentFilter` for it. Register it in your `Service`. And than send `Intent` with action that you add to `IntentFilter` from any of your Applications.

Go throw [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to get better understanding of Intents